# Cropping image with minimum height and width android

Tags: android, image, crop

I tried a lot of libraries and I don't found how can I specify a minimum width and height of cropped image. I found similar question but it was old. Is there any way to do this on android? I found this [library](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2366) but it allow only to specify min frame size with ratio 1:1, not for any rectangle.

Comment: minimum size of cropped image is 1 x 1 (one pixel) but i'm sure it is not what you want...

Comment: I want to be able to specify my own minimum width and height

Comment: Did you try https://github.com/joshdholtz/CropImageView ?

Comment: I don't see any setter for minimum dimensions in this library source code